# How can I detect if my python script/code was ran from a python unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am looking for an elegant way to detect if my script was ran from a unittest harness or was triggered by normal execution. So far I am looking into the call stack for the `'unittest.py'` string. However I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way to achieve the same result.

```
def hasRunFromUnitTest():
    intest = False
    for path, _, _, _ in traceback.extract_stack():
        if 'unittest.py' in path:
            intest = True
            break
    return intest
```

Agree with comments below this is clearly a hack however I am using a complex layering of technologies of which I do not always have access to the underlying API/Framework code underneath. In this particular case I have a .Net application launching a custom python environment which is used to build .Net UI. At times the underlying .NET process is never killed on application exit and I need to manually kill it this has the side effect of of killing my unit test harness as well.

Ideally I would be looking for some kind of property or constant in the `unittest` class.

Comment: This seems... somewhat foolish. Why do you think you need this? If the code behaves differently under test, *what's the point of testing?!*

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Checking if your script was run from unittest is not elegant in the first place (IMHO). If you really want to do this anyway I think a solution similar to your is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be more "pythonic":

```
def hasRunFromUnitTest():
    return 'unittest' in sys.modules
```